# Take lines between two specific values from different columns in a txt file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, text, command-line

How can I get the lines contained between values of different columns from a .txt file?

I have a text file (as shown below) with many columns and I need to get the lines contained between the position of the second column to the position of the third column.

```
1       10385389        10385390        .       21
1       10385390        10385391        .       22
1       10385391        10385392        .       22
1       10385392        10385393        .       21
1       10385393        10385394        .       22
1       10385394        10385395        .       25
1       10385395        10385396        .       25
1       10385396        10385397        .       25
1       10385397        10385398        .       25
1       10385398        10385399        .       25
```

Taking this example imagine I want to select from 10385391 to 10385397  which desired output would be

```
1       10385391        10385392        .       22
1       10385392        10385393        .       21
1       10385393        10385394        .       22
1       10385394        10385395        .       25
1       10385395        10385396        .       25
1       10385396        10385397        .       25
```

Bonus: It is also important that if the start position is not found take instead the closes one. In the example provided that is not gonna happen because there is a correlative serie but in case I get a file like this

```
1       10385389        10385390        .       21
1       10385391        10385392        .       22
1       10385392        10385393        .       21
1       10385393        10385394        .       22
```

I would like to avoid an error if the user introduces 10385390 and this is not found in the second column.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Is that what you mean?

Comment: Its highly encouraged on Stack overflow for questioners to add their code which they tried to solve their own problem, so please add it to avoid downvotes and close votes, thank you, cheers.

Comment: Is the second field always smaller than the third field?

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v sn="10385390" -v en="10385397" '$2>=sn && $3<=en {print;next}{exit}' "file"
```

- `sn="10385390"` For the start number.
- `en="10385397"` For the end number.
- `"file"` Your input file.

Change these variables according to your needs.